# Azure Active Directory - access token group information

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

We have Azure Active Directory set up and are connecting to a 3rd party application using Azure AD. The access token (from fiddler) does not have groups information. I went through [configuring-groups-optional-claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-groups-optional-claims). What's confusing is that it says to update the Manage token for the Application. What I am trying to understand is if it is the 3rd party that needs to enable sending group information or should it be a configuration that we should be able to manage.

What does it mean to "Select the application you want to configure optional claims for in the list". We do not own the 3rd party application.

Answer (score 1):

The access token will only contain groups if that API's app registration says it should.
So it is the 3rd party application developer's choice in your case.

Comment: So, how would the 3rd party application know which groups to send as part of the access token? The groups would be configured in the company's AD